# How to protect folder from being removed/moved, but no constraint for files inside

Tags: permissions, xattr

Here's what I want to achieve:

I want to protect folder `/mnt/sdmmc0p2/test` from being removed or moved, 
but files inside can be removed.

I try to use `chattr +a /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test`, but fail.

```
~# chattr +a /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
~# mkdir /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
~# chattr +a /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
~# date >> /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test/test
~# rm /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test/test
rm: can't remove '/mnt/sdmmc0p2/test/test': Operation not permitted
```

Then I try 'u' (undeletable) flag

```
~# chattr =u /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
~# rm /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test/test
~# rm -r /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
```

Here's two questions:

1. Can my goal being achieved by `chattr`?
2. Why 'u' flag is not working? Do I misunderstand meaning of "undeletable"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with `chmod` and `chown`

```
sudo chown root:root /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
sudo chmod 777  /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
```

then to test

```
cd  /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
touch mytest1
rm mytest1
cd ..
rm -rf  /mnt/sdmmc0p2/test
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/sdmmc0p2/test': Permission denied
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, real user in my system would be root, and I want to ban root user from deleting this folder.